# Clojure subseq returns incorrect values

Tags: clojure

I have this sorted map:

```
(def sm (sorted-map :1 "a" :500 "b" :9999 "c"))
;; {:1 "a", :500 "b", :9999 "c"}
```

I'm trying to get a sequence with all keys that are lower than :1000:

```
(subseq sm < :1000)
```

I was expecting the output to be this:

```
([:1 "a"] [:500 "b"])
```

But instead I'm getting this:

```
([:1 "a"])
```

Why is :1000 between :1 and :500, or :5000 between :1 and :500 ?

I've tried the same with string keys or number keys, same result.

Thanks.

Comment: For me it works with number keys, I get:  `([1 "a"] [500 "b"])`.

Comment: @jas You're right. I'm not sure what I did differently before, but it works for me now with the number keys. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keywords sort similarly to strings, not integer values.  If you want to sort by integer keys, use integer-valued keys, e.g. 1, 500, 1000, not `:1`, `:500`, `:1000`.  Keys in Clojure maps need not be keywords.

Comment: Here is a guide on the Clojure.org web site explaining the behavior of the default comparator function clojure.core/compare not only for keywords, but other types of values: https://clojure.org/guides/comparators#_clojures_default_comparator

Comment: Thank you. I'll definitely check that.

Answer (score 1):

Andy's answer already clarifies your issue, but I wanted to point out that [clojure.data.avl](https://github.com/clojure/data.avl) implements high-performance sorted sets and maps.  Among their many features is included sub-ranges:

```
 (avl/subrange (avl/sorted-set 0 1 2 3 4 5) > 1)
 ;= #{2 3 4 5}

 (avl/subrange (avl/sorted-set 0 1 2 3 4 5) <= 4)
 ;= #{0 1 2 3 4}

 (avl/subrange (avl/sorted-set 0 1 2 3 4 5) >= 2 < 5)
 ;= #{2 3 4}
```

Comment: That library does support those things, and so do Clojure core's built-in sorted-set and sorted-map implementations.  I would not be surprised if clojure.data.avl might support features that sorted-set and sorted-map do, but I have half a recollection that for the features they have in common, clojure.data.avl is measurably slower -- not so much that you would want to avoid it for casual use, but you would probably want to prefer the built-in sorted sets and maps if it was in more performance sensitive areas of your code, or even consider something besides Clojure's implementations.